# Pidgin systray disappeared suddenly in 13.04 with Unity

Tags: unity, 13.04, pidgin, system-tray

About since a week only the pidgin systray disappeared (maybe after an ubuntu update).
Pidgin works well, but it can be seen only in the message indicator. I tried restart Unity, I tried reboot, but nothing helped.

I used 13.04. The [required configs](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html) have been set.

Any idea?

I could not find anything about it.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I just installed this plugin: http://nevitus.com/2013/05/unity-integration-for-pidgin/

If you just want the plugin, scroll all the way down. It integrates perfectly with the Unity desktop.

Comment: Thx, I will check it.